# Get UTC format from String Datetime

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have datetime in string format. What I need is to get the UTC format for the same datetime string so that I could send it on backend server. But also i need to send the correct UTC time means according to the time zone.

Example: I have a datetime string as "30-09-2016 22:10" now from this I need a UTC format. Since this datetime string is obtained from my app used in India, so the converted UTC format should be in correct form.

Comment: What is a *UTC format*?

Answer (score 0):

When a `DateTime` is created in an app, usually it is `DateTimeKind.Local`, so you can just use the `ToUniversalTime()`method before you send it to your server.

If you have a string, just use `DateTime.Parse`, it would create a `Local` date time, which you can use like I explained above.